# How to concatenate 2 multiline strings line by line, like 'paste' does with two files

Tags: bash, concatenation, multiline

I'm searching for a way to concatenate two multiline strings line by line, like paste does with file contents. Is there a equivalent tool like `paste` for multiline strings? REMARKS:
I don't want to use files in any manner!

String content 1:

```
A1 
A2
A3
A4
```

String content 2:

```
B5
B6
B7
```

I would like to have:

```
A1 B5
A2 B6
A3 B7
A4
```

Maybe with results like a full outer join, having an empty column entry on every position where no data is given? That would be interesting, too: e.g.

```
A1 B5 C8
A2 B6 C9
A3 B7 C10
A4    C11
```

As an example:

```
> string3=$(combine "$string1" "$string2")
> echo "$string3"
> A1 B5
  A2 B6
  A3 B7
  A4
```

Thanks for tips and hints ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `paste` for this, without making use of files!

```
$ paste -d' ' <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2")
A1 B5
A2 B6
A3 B7
A4
```

Comment: Ok, then I was close to that solution :), but missed the echo and changing the delimeter to `-d' '`

Answer (score 1):

'paste' can do the concatenation with more than two files.

cat file1

```
A1 
A2
A3
A4
```

cat file2

```
B5
B6
B7
```

cat file3

```
C8
C9
C10
C11
```

Can you please try

```
paste file1 file2 file3 > output
```

For me, I got this

```
A1  B5  C8
A2  B6  C9
A3  B7  C10
A4      C11
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: This is what I want, but more precicly I don't want to use `paste` to concatenate files columns, because I know this functionality already. I'm searching a more elegant way than using files and concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way in bash would be to convert the strings to arrays and then simply write the data out in tab separated format based upon the longest string. Here is a quick example:

```
#!/bin/bash

outfile="${1:-colcomb.txt}"
:> $outfile

s1='A1 
A2
A3
A4'

s2='B5
B6
B7'

## read into arrays
ar1=( $s1 )
ar2=( $s2 )

## use largest array to drive output
if test "${#ar1[@]}" -ge "${#ar2[@]}" ; then
    for ((i=0; i<${#ar1[@]}; i++)); do
        echo -n "${ar1[$i]}" >> $outfile
        test -n "${ar2[$i]}" && echo -e "\t${ar2[$i]}" >> $outfile
    done
    echo "" >> $outfile  # append newline to file (optional)
else
    for ((i=0; i<${#ar2[@]}; i++)); do
        test -n "${ar1[$i]}" && echo -n "${ar1[$i]}" >> $outfile
        echo -e "\t${ar2[$i]}" >> $outfile
    done
    echo "" >> $outfile  # append newline to file (optional)
fi

exit 0
```

output:

```
$ bash ap2col.sh

$ cat colcomb.txt
A1      B5
A2      B6
A3      B7
A4
```

That way you could add a third or fourth string if required.

Comment: and now in posix shell ;-)