# Interleave two multiline strings in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to do exactly what has been in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798817/how-to-concatenate-2-multiline-strings-line-by-line-like-paste-does-with-two), except in Python. Consider two strings:

```
s1='AAA1
    AAA2
    AAA3'
s2='BBB1
    BBB2
    BBB3'
```

I want to have `combine(s1,s2)` to return:

```
s3='AAA1BBB1
    AAA2BBB2
    AAA3BBB3'
```

You may consider that these strings are actually very long and I want this processes to be performant. I would appreciate if you could help me know how to do this.

Comment: Such multiline string syntax isn't allowed in Python. Do you mean there is a newline between each line and the leading spaces are omitted?

Comment: @MichaelButscher true. strings are indeed multiline and I want to stack them horizontally. I'm not saying the solution is trivial. that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiline-strings are denoted with `'''` in Python.

```
>>> s1 = '''AAA1
...:AAA2
...:AAA3'''
>>> 
>>> s2 = '''BBB1
...:BBB2
...:BBB3'''
```

You can split them with `str.splitlines` and interleave them with `zip`.

```
>>> strings = [s1, s2]
>>> pairs = zip(*(s.splitlines() for s in strings))
>>> result = '\n'.join(''.join(pair) for pair in pairs)
>>> 
>>> print(result)
AAA1BBB1
AAA2BBB2
AAA3BBB3
```

A generic function that accepts any number of multiline strings using the `*args` syntax can be written as follows.

```
>>> def combine(*strings):
...:    lines = zip(*(s.splitlines() for s in strings))
...:    return '\n'.join(''.join(line) for line in lines)
>>> 
>>> str1 = '''A
...:D
...:H'''
>>> str2 = '''B
...:E
...:I'''
>>> str3 = '''C
...:F
...:J'''
>>> 
>>> print(combine(str1, str2, str3))
ABC
DEF
HIJ
```

Note that `zip` truncates the iterable it produces to the length of its shortest argument, i.e. the result has as many lines as the shortest multiline string passed to `combine`.

If you expect strings with different numbers of lines and need fill-values, you can play around with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from the `itertools` module.

Comment: This seems great. let me try it and come back to you.

Comment: I used this solution [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53164538/4999991) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for what you're looking to get if there's newlines involved:

```
s1="AAA1\nAAA2\nAAA3"
s2="BBB1\nBBB2\nBBB3"

ms1 = s1.splitlines()
ms2 = s2.splitlines()

new_list = []

i = 0
while i < 3:
  new_list.append( ms1[i]+ms2[i] )
  i = i + 1

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Probably a better idea to use `for i in range(3)` loop in this case, it will already provide you with an auto-incremented index.

Answer (score 1):

Use `splitlines()` and then `zip` two list together

```
s1="AAA1\nAAA2\nAAA3"
s2="BBB1\nBBB2\nBBB3"

l1 = s1.splitlines()
l2 = s2.splitlines()

print('\n'.join([i+j for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]))
```

Output

```
AAA1BBB1
AAA2BBB2
AAA3BBB3
```